# Electron: Should I still consider asar if I am already using a bundler (Webpack)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, electron-packager, asar

The [electron-packager docs](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#asar) mention three reasons why I might want to consider packaging my app into an asar archive (the Electron-specific archive format):

1. Avoid issues with long path names on Windows
2. Speed up `require()` calls in my code
3. Make it slightly harder for the end user to inspect the source code (they have to first download asar and un-archive the app)

Now, I am already using Webpack, which already bundles all my JS into one file, so:

1. No long nested path names -> No long path name issues on Windows
2. No `require()` calls in the code -> Nothing to speed up
3. I can minify and uglify the code -> Already pretty obfuscated

On the flipside, it seems to me that using asar could potentially be a risk, because it adds another layer of logic. It's an abstraction that could [leak](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/).

What am I missing?

Are there reasons why I should still consider asar, even when using Webpack?